Can the modal logic S5 be reduced to Rosser's system for a first order function calculus?
From the SEP

In propositional logic, a valuation of the atomic sentences (or row of a truth table) assigns a truth value
(
T
or
F
)
to each propositional variable
p
. Then the truth values of the complex sentences are calculated with truth tables. In modal semantics, a set
W
of possible worlds is introduced. A valuation then gives a truth value to each propositional variable for each of the possible worlds in
W
. This means the value assigned to
p
for world
w
may differ from the value assigned to
p
for another world
w
′
.

My question is can you interpret possible worlds as the possible rows of a truth table?
Let Φ be an arbitrary statement composed of n simple statements (atomic sentences) A1,A2,...,An.  Then
Φ=Φ(A1,A2,...,An).
Using Tarski's truth schema
|Φ|=1 iff Φ, where |Φ| is the truth value of the proposition denoted by Φ
Now it seems to me that an equivalent definition of necessity is
□Φ iff ∀x1∈S∀x2∈S...∀xn∈S[Φ], where S is the set of simple statements.
Why this should work: Since the universal quantifiers are over the set of simple statements, the definition holds for statements which denote propositions whose truth value varies in time.  Thus, by universally quantifying over all simple statements, you include temporal statements in the domain.  Thus, a statement like Φ= [A∧(A→B)]→B will be necessarily true if it's possible A,B denote propositions whose truth value varies in time, and when that's the case |Φ|=1.  So by universally quantifying over all simple statements you include temporal statements, so saying
∀x1∈S∀x2∈S...∀xn∈S[Φ]
is equivalent to saying|Φ|=1 in every row.
With this approach, S5 is merely an extension of the first order function calculus Rosser's system RS_1, and you don't have the messy symbolism of possible worlds semantics.
You can show the axioms of S5 are provable, and the necessitation rule is derivable.
Propositional Modal Logic (S5)
Distribution axiom: □(φ → ψ)→ (□φ → □ψ)
(M) □φ → φ
(5) ◇φ → □◇φ
Rule of Necessitation (RN): ⊢ □φ follows from ⊢ φ
In RS_1 you can prove
∀x[φ → ψ]→ (∀x [φ] → ∀x[ψ])
From that, and the suggested definition for □φ, you can prove the distribution axiom of S5.
In RS_1, one of the axioms is
P5. ∀ x [Φ] → Φ(x_n), where x_n is any specific individual constant, and Φ(x_n) is the result of replacing all free occurrences of x in Φ by x_n. (In the event there are no free occurrences of x in Φ, Φ(x_n) = Φ
From that and the suggested definition, you can prove axiom (M) of S5.
In RS_1, for FOL, you need two underived rules of inference:
R1: P, P → Q; therefore Q
R2: Φ(α); therefore ∀x[Φ].
From R2 you can derive the necessitation rule of S5.
Derived Rule NEC: ⊢ Φ therefore ⊢ □Φ

⊢ Φ

By analyticity, Φ is a truth table tautology, given that FOL is reducible to the propositional calculus. It has no free variables, therefore
Φ = Φ(A1,A2,...,An), where the Ai's are arbitrary simple statements.

⊢ Φ(A1,A2,...,An)
⊢ ∀x1 ∀x2...∀xn[if x1∈S ∧ x2∈S ∧...∧ xn∈S then Φ(x1,x2,...,xn) [n applications of R2]
⊢ ∀x1∈S∀x2∈S...∀xn∈S[Φ(x1,x2,...,xn)] [3;Df]
⊢ □Φ [4;Df]

The remainder can be omitted.

There has been much discussion about my use of arbitrary constants.  Kit Fine beautifully agrees with me, that they are necessary for proper reasoning.
Reasoning with arbitrary objects.
In order to bring my terminology in line with Fine's I will henceforth use the following definitions.
Definitions
C is an arbitrary constant iff ∀x[◇x=C]
C is a specific constant iff ∃! x[x=C]
C is a general constant iff ∀x[◇x=C] ∨ ∃! x[x=C]
I have reversed my definitions of arbitrary constant and general constant, in order to match Fine's use of the word 'arbitrary'.
Suppose you are working with some domain of discourse D.  Then you have universally quantified statements such as
∀x[x ∈ D → φ(x)]
Kit Fine's notion of arbitrary object is really the notion of arbitrary element of some domain
D.
Universal Instantiation
∀x[Φ]; therefore Φ(x_n), where x_n is a general constant.
Let α be an arbitrary constant.  By universal Instantiation
α ∈ D → φ(α).
So if you know α ∈ D, by modus ponens φ(α).
Universal Generalization
Φ(α); therefore ∀x[Φ], where α is an arbitrary constant, and Φ is either an arbitrary propositional function of x, or an arbitrary Wff.
Suppose α ∈ D, how can you apply UG?
Well, suppose you also know φ(α).  Then you know
α ∈ D ∧ φ(α)
Thus you know
α ∈ D → φ(α)
Now by UG you get
∀x[x ∈ D → φ(x)]
So using a definition you know
∀x ∈ D[φ(x)]
Thus Kit Fine's notion of an arbitrary object is precisely the notion of α ∈ D, where α is my notion of an arbitrary constant.

This is unreadable. Links to SEP and Fine are enough, so delete the quotes, compress the text and spell out how it is related to the title. Your 'definitions' are still nonsensical and Fine introduces arbitrary objects in a different manner. Use his setup.
